# .NET Mvc3 Antiforgerytoken

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, antiforgerytoken

In a .Net MVC3 web application, how can I get the `AntiForgeryToken`? The `HtmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken()` returns the token wrapped by a hidden field, but I just want the token. Is there an option to retrieve only the value?

This is for a piece of javascript which does a POST to a url (without form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. [It comes out of System.Web.Helpers that way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.antiforgery.aspx). The actual implementation of the token is in an internal class.

On the other hand, your JavaScript can read the value of a hidden field, with or without a form.